# Using Selenium and Java to download multiple files to multiple locations

Tags: java, selenium

I'm currently using Selenium to pull some data from a few dozen MFD printers around our campus, and it's mostly coming along well. I can get logged in, click through the menus, and download *a file* to *a location that I set*. What I need to do though, is to log into each printer in turn and download the same file to a different folder. So far, the relevant code looks like this:

```
    chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);

    HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
    options.addArguments("--test-type");

    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

    webDriver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
    wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20);
    String fileName = "Y:/MFDAutomationEnv/test_mfd_list.txt";

    readFile(fileName);
    if(fileData == null){
        logPrint("Couldn't read from " + fileName);
        return;
    }

    for(int currentMFD = 0; currentMFD < fileData.length; currentMFD++){
        //navigate
        mfdDownloadButton(ip);
        mfdLogout(ip);
    }

private static int mfdDownloadButton(String ip){
    try{

        chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath + "someSubDirectory/");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("btnEXE"))).click();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        logPrint("Failed to find download button for " + ip);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So basically, is there a way to change the download location on the fly without having to reinstantiate an entirely new webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is configuring your browser to automatically download files to specified location. There is another approach you can possibly use. After navigating to a page where button to download your file is located, can you grab URL of the file? If yes, you can use Apache HttpClient to download the file. [Here](http://jsystem.org/downloading-files-using-selenium-and-apache-httpclient/) is the good article about it.